# Assigned `nullptr` to `bool` type. Which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, gcc, boolean, clang, nullptr

I have a following snippet of code that assigned `nullptr` to `bool` type.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool b = nullptr;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

In **clang 3.8.0** working fine. it's give an output `0`. [Clang Demo](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang)

But **g++  5.4.0** give an error:

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:5:18: error: converting to ‘bool’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ requires direct-initialization [-fpermissive]
         bool b = nullptr;
```

**Which compiler is correct?**

Comment: I get a compiler warning when running it in the live compiler you linked. "warning: implicit conversion of nullptr constant to 'bool' [-Wnull-conversion]"

Comment: According to the error given by GCC (and MSVC) and the section in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) I'd say that it is not allowed by the standard (and Clang allows it as an extension)

Comment: It darn well shouldn't be. One of the whole points of `nullptr` was to make using a pointer in a boolean context a well-defined thing to do. :-/ But, I can see how it might be correct to at least warn about direct conversion in the form of an assignment like that. Does the compiler still give an error when you have `nullptr && true` instead of just `nullptr`?

Comment: Has anyone confirmed clang version of boolean accepting `nullptr` on a Linux machine by any chance? Though I wouldn't be surprised if there existed such a case on a Linux machine. I've seen weird things over there.

Comment: @VG Clang 3.8 [gives a warning](https://godbolt.org/g/yS5Nuv) on Linux for this even without any `-W` options.

Comment: @Omnifarious The point of `nullptr` was to be *more* type-safe than just `NULL`. It shouldn’t implicitly convert to anything except a pointer or some other type that defines a conversion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the C++ Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true. **For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.**

So this declaration

```
bool b( nullptr );
```

is valid and this

```
bool b = nullptr;
```

is wrong.

I myself pointed out already this problem at [isocpp](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/UXjHK44aSmQ)

Comment: The C++11 standard has different verbiage. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.bool. Is text in your post from a later version of the standard?

Comment: Though, why did it work fine on clang 3.8.0 as OP stated? Did it interpret `nullptr` as a 0 in clang by any chance? (Less likely though)

Comment: Is there a bit missing? I think it should be "So this declaration is correct" (for the first snippet)

Comment: @RSahu seems that was reported as a defect later on: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1423

Comment: I do not follow, how em-phased quote leads to conclusion that first snippet is wrong.

Comment: @Slava, it implies that conversion of `nullptr_t` to `bool` is not allowed in any other context. Too bad it's not explicit.

Comment: @RSahu but first snippet is exactly what defined there, is it not?

Comment: @Slava There was a typo in my post due to problems with internet.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I hope you fixed your internet mate. Now I'm slightly confused of why clang accepted and assigned 0 from `= nullptr` to the boolean value. It shouldn't work as `nullptr` is specifically for pointers.

Comment: @VG as you can see in the defect report and the thread linked in the answer the C++11 standard originally allowed this conversion and so compilers implemented it - it was later "fixed", but apparently Clang still treats it only as a warning (presumably to not break some existing code that might have used this?)

Comment: @UnholySheep very weird indeed. I'm glad they are aware of its effect on boolean. This could cause some confusion. Maybe on the future versions, they may deprecate it towards non-pointer types.

Answer (score 2):

This was changed by [DR 1423](https://wg21.link/cwg1423) so that there is no implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `bool`.

(The relevant wording changed again very recently by [DR 1781](https://wg21.link/cwg1781) and [DR 2133](https://wg21.link/cwg2133) but only to move the wording, not change what conversions are valid. At the time of writing, the CWG issues list doesn't show that 1781 has been resolved, but the change to the draft is at [visible in git](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/df3e38121431afd9adcf7dce725a670a235463ea#diff-64a673ab7a20068092a4cf86b36f4334).)

So it looks to me like Clang 3.8 implements the pre-1423 rule, and GCC 5.4 implements the post-1423 rule which doesn't allow implicit conversions from `nullptr` to `bool`.

Current versions of Clang still allow the conversion, but give a `-Wnull-conversion` warning.